# Tracking login/logout time of workbook where workbook may not be saved

Tags: excel, vba, save

I have a workbook that tracks the user and time when logged into and logged out of.

The logout is triggered by a button or by closing the workbook.

Someone may want to **not** save the work they have done in the workbook but I would still like to see when they logged in and out on my audit log.

Is there a way to only save data in one sheet and not the entire workbook?

Comment: Either save the workbook or not. You can save only one sheet as a new workbook, but I assume that this is not what you are looking for...

Comment: Might be better to have your code log the information somewhere else, such as to a separate text file in the same folder as the workbook.

Comment: Agreed with @TimWilliams. Security would be my main concern though. Someone could easily track down and change the log. May not matter to you, but it may.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is an audit log you can do that with a text file pretty easily. However you are currently logging your "log ins" can be modified to either log that into that sheet AND another excel workbook or a text file as mentioned. You can obviously edit the path to save to whatever directory you would like. Be sure to create a Log.txt (or whatever) file first also. Similarly, you can add in other variables if you are so inclined to capture them, which I assume you already have in your existing code. The open statements in this code aren't reflected on the screen. It pops up a task in event viewer and then closes it.

```
Sub LogIn()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim TxtLog As String
    Dim i As Integer

    i = FreeFile
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Log.txt"
    Open Path For Input As i
    TxtLog = Input(LOF(i), i) & vbCr & Now()'read entire log file into string and add new info
    Close i 'close log.txt for reading to VBA

    i = FreeFile

    Open Path For Output As i 'open log.txt to write to it from VBA
    Print #i, TxtLog 
    Close i
End Sub
```